# Ionic v1 open populated .sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm creating an ionic v1 project.
I have a `sqlite` database with 3 tables, and I would like to display the data in 3 different pages, preferably with ngCordova.
My database is this:
[dados.sqlite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj7Ms.png)

I tried several methods and example but didn't work.
I need some very detailed example since I am not aware of `SQLite`.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the purpose of the database?

Comment: I tried using $ cordovaSQLite.
my purpose is to display in each of the 3 pages, the data contained in each of the tables.
these tables are a glossary, containing the id (1) acronym (AAA) and description (This is the AAA).
I do not know if I was understood

Comment: I tried to follow this example https://codepad.co/snippet/131f3b but I do not know what data I should change